# find replace and append not working

Tags: replace, find, append

Help with sed,

I'm trying to use sed to find and replace plus append at the end of the line a
variable, but I do not know how about to append with at end of the line.

I want to add the variable +$APPEND
to display like this:

```
ldap_uri = ldaps://third.pirulo.net,ldap_uri = ldaps://primary.pirulo.net,ldap_uri = ldaps://secondary.pirulo.net
```

Any help will really appreciated.

```
I001="primary.pirulo.net"
I002="secondary.pirulo.net"
I003="third.pirulo.net"
SSSD="/etc/sssd/sssd.conf"
APPEND="ldap_uri = ldaps://secondary.pirulo.net"

/bin/sed 's/'$I001'/'$I003'/;s/'$I002'/'$I001'/' +$APPEND $SSSD
```

Comment: What do you want to append to which line(s)? Could you show us the desired result?

Comment: I am still not sure that I understand your question, but you can append something to the end of each line with `sed 's/$/something/'`

Comment: I try that but it doesn't work. What I'm trying to accomplish is this. On my sed command I have two sed commands. I'm switching from 1 to 3 and add 2 at the end of the line, but what it doesn't work is right after the second command is add 2 right after 1.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, and you are attempting to do too many things together. Here is my best effort:

```
sed -e "s/$I001/$I003/" -e "s/$I002/$I001/" -e "s/$/$APPEND/" $SSSD
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. I really appreciate. It did not work. if you look at  https://itservices.stanford.edu/service/directory/pam-sssd this sssd.conf file under Install and Configure SSSD # 2 you will find ldap_uri = ldap://ldap.stanford.edu you will have an idea